# Unexpected null-pointer-exception (NPE) in Hibernate findDirty during commit

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I get the following stacktrace and I don't know where to look. Any insights? To my knowledge I'm using the entitymanager in a threadsafe way but the codebase is quite large so can't be 100% sure. Is that the direction to search for the problem?

The error happens rarely and repeating the exact same steps in the application does not trigger the bug again.

Hibernate version 5.5.7

```
javax.persistence.RollbackException: Error while committing the transaction
at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convertCommitException(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:81)
at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:104)
at com.zzz.base.AbstractEditPageManager.updateButtonAction(AbstractEditPageManager.java:533)
at com.zzz.pages.client.ConsultManager.updateButtonAction(ConsultManager.java:4470)
at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1766.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:246)
at org.apache.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:266)
at org.jboss.weld.module.web.util.el.ForwardingMethodExpression.invoke(ForwardingMethodExpression.java:40)
at org.jboss.weld.module.web.el.WeldMethodExpression.invoke(WeldMethodExpression.java:50)
at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.el.ContextAwareTagMethodExpression.invoke(ContextAwareTagMethodExpression.java:96)
at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.el.LocationMethodExpression.invoke(LocationMethodExpression.java:128)
at javax.faces.event.MethodExpressionActionListener.processAction(MethodExpressionActionListener.java:78)
at javax.faces.event.ActionEvent.processListener(ActionEvent.java:58)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.broadcast(UIComponentBase.java:429)
at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:103)
at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot._broadcastAll(UIViewRoot.java:1255)
at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:420)
at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot._process(UIViewRoot.java:1741)
at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:935)
at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationExecutor.execute(InvokeApplicationExecutor.java:42)
at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.executePhase(LifecycleImpl.java:195)
at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:142)
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:204)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
at com.zzz.base.filter.NoCacheFilter.doFilter(NoCacheFilter.java:35)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
at com.zzz.base.filter.MDCFilter.doFilter(MDCFilter.java:29)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
at com.zzz.base.filter.BindRequestToThreadFilter.doFilter(BindRequestToThreadFilter.java:24)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
at com.zzz.base.filter.AddRequestInfoToSessionFilter.doFilter(AddRequestInfoToSessionFilter.java:25)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
at com.zzz.base.filter.SynchronizePostFilter.doFilter(SynchronizePostFilter.java:84)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:667)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:357)
at org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpProcessor.service(AjpProcessor.java:433)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:893)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1726)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.hibernate.type.TypeHelper.findDirty(TypeHelper.java:313)
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.findDirty(AbstractEntityPersister.java:4737)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.dirtyCheck(DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.java:584)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.isUpdateNecessary(DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.java:245)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.onFlushEntity(DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.java:170)
at org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:107)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.flushEntities(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:229)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.flushEverythingToExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:93)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:39)
at org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:107)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.doFlush(SessionImpl.java:1391)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:482)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flushBeforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:3274)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:2409)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(JdbcCoordinatorImpl.java:449)
at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.beforeCompletionCallback(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:183)
at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.access$300(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:40)
at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl$TransactionDriverControlImpl.commit(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:281)
at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:101)
... 59 more
```

I also get this stacktrace where the stacktrace does not say where the NPE was. Annoying...

```
 javax.persistence.RollbackException: Error while committing the transaction
at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convertCommitException(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:81)
at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:104)
at com.zzz.base.AbstractEditPageManager.updateButtonAction(AbstractEditPageManager.java:533)
at com.zzz.pages.client.ConsultManager.updateButtonAction(ConsultManager.java:4470)
at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1766.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:246)
at org.apache.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:266)
at org.jboss.weld.module.web.util.el.ForwardingMethodExpression.invoke(ForwardingMethodExpression.java:40)
at org.jboss.weld.module.web.el.WeldMethodExpression.invoke(WeldMethodExpression.java:50)
at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.el.ContextAwareTagMethodExpression.invoke(ContextAwareTagMethodExpression.java:96)
at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.el.LocationMethodExpression.invoke(LocationMethodExpression.java:128)
at javax.faces.event.MethodExpressionActionListener.processAction(MethodExpressionActionListener.java:78)
at javax.faces.event.ActionEvent.processListener(ActionEvent.java:58)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.broadcast(UIComponentBase.java:429)
at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:103)
at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot._broadcastAll(UIViewRoot.java:1255)
at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:420)
at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot._process(UIViewRoot.java:1741)
at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:935)
at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationExecutor.execute(InvokeApplicationExecutor.java:42)
at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.executePhase(LifecycleImpl.java:195)
at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:142)
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:204)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
at com.zzz.base.filter.NoCacheFilter.doFilter(NoCacheFilter.java:35)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
at com.zzz.base.filter.MDCFilter.doFilter(MDCFilter.java:29)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
at com.zzz.base.filter.BindRequestToThreadFilter.doFilter(BindRequestToThreadFilter.java:24)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
at com.zzz.base.filter.AddRequestInfoToSessionFilter.doFilter(AddRequestInfoToSessionFilter.java:25)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
at com.zzz.base.filter.SynchronizePostFilter.doFilter(SynchronizePostFilter.java:84)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:667)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:357)
at org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpProcessor.service(AjpProcessor.java:433)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:893)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1726)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Comment: maybe study this: https://vladmihalcea.com/how-to-customize-hibernate-dirty-checking-mechanism/

Comment: Please create an issue in the issue tracker(https://hibernate.atlassian.net) with a test case(https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-test-case-templates/blob/master/orm/hibernate-orm-5/src/test/java/org/hibernate/bugs/JPAUnitTestCase.java) that reproduces the issue.

Comment: Thanks, I'm indeed planning to create a minimal test but that might not be that easy. Seems to be related with the order of persisting related entities. Like persisting the child of a parent first and then the parent it has a link to. But the message should be something like 'unmanaged entity'

Comment: See https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-14823